# LWC lightning data table with column level validation

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

Ref:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

For a lightning data table with inline edit function.
I am trying to understand how to call a JS validation when the user edits a column in a LWC lightning data table and Tabs out of the column. (Instead of checking this onSave functionality)

Also, by default if the column is email field or website an inbuilt client side validation is invoked to check the format of website or email, (In the same way can I also validate the length of the fields ?? )

Thank you,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you are referring to tab out from a cell instead of a column. If that's what you mean, you can capture it using `oncellchange` event.

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation):

> You can handle the `oncancel`, `oncellchange`, and `onsave` actions when the cell value changes or is saved. When the `onsave` action is used, the Cancel and Save button appears after a value cell changes and you press the Enter or Tab key, or move away from the cell.

Remember though, you will need to manipulate the values in the cell to be able to perform any validation as this event will be fired from any cell change and tab outs.

My personal approach will not to implement any validations on tab if you are really looking to edit things in table but wait until you are saving the table so that you are able to reduce the multiple back and forth communication.

Comment: Thank you Jayant, Yes I was looking for onCellChange.